# Amcharts legend dynamic resizing

Tags: amcharts

I want my legend to adjust itslef according to the amount of data that is coming in like highcharts . For example if I have only one legend I don't wanna legend to take the length as the div itself and I also have multiple pods .if there are a lot of legends I want it to have scrollbar instead now it's reducing the size of the chart itself.
Pls give your valuable inputs .

Answer (score 1):

You can have the [Legend](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend) rendered inside a defined `Element` referring to it using [divId](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#divId).

Then just make sure your legend element is setup to use scrollbars.

Please check the example here: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/dac1c66de18a50661c8195d4b792a30c